# UITableViewController on top of SDL window does not accept clicks

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, sdl

For porting gurus that use SDL on iOS:

I am using SDL 2.0.

I am able to display a simple ViewController / NavigationController on top of the main SDL window, showing a few labels and buttons. Callbacks work, so far so good.

Now I want to be able to push a secondary TableViewController on top of the previous view controller. It displays well, populating with data - so some delegate methods work.

However - the TableViewController does not accept clicks. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is never called. The delegate of the tableView is correct though as it is set to the TableViewController itself.

If I use the same code of the TableViewController in any other iOS project, it works perfect.

It is actually not a specific UITableViewController issue - I had the same problem with UIPickerView control, which hadn't worked either, as if some delegate callbacks were ignored ...

What do I have to do to get the whole thing started? In which cases does a UITableViewController ignore clicks / selections?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

SDL messes with the message loop. See this fix for further information:

https://bitbucket.org/DavidLudwig/sdl/changeset/50df56423bee